# How to align an ascii character and text side by side?

Tags: html, css

In the example below, how can you make the text "Menu" be vertically aligned (middle) along side of the burger menu?

```css
#burger { font-size:2em; }
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="burger">&#x2261</span> Menu
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vertical-align` with the value that suits you the best:

https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align

> The vertical-align property affects the vertical positioning inside a line box of the boxes generated by an inline-level element.

example

```css
#burger { font-size:2em; vertical-align:-0.15em;}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="burger">&#x2261</span> Menu
</div>
```

Comment: that's cool, didn't know vertical-align accepts specific length.